# BDD symfony 3 cleaning database - An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: bdd, symfony

When I do not try to clean up the database, everything works - tests can connect to database.

Part of the test is this:

```
namespace tests\ApiBundle\features\group_management\bootstrap;

use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Behat\Context\SnippetAcceptingContext;
use tests\ApiBundle\features\WebApi;
use PHPUnit_Framework_Assert as Assertions;
//use Behat\Testwork\Hook\Scope\BeforeSuiteScope;
//use Behat\Testwork\Hook\Scope\AfterSuiteScope;
//use Behat\Behat\Hook\Scope\AfterScenarioScope;
use Behat\Behat\Hook\Scope\BeforeScenarioScope;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

use NG\Model\Group\Group;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\ORMExecutor;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Loader;
use tests\MyDataFixtures\LoadUserData;


/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class CreatingNewGroupContext implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext
{
    /**
     * @var WebApi
     */
    private $webApi;

    /**
     * Initializes context.
     *
     * Every scenario gets its own context instance.
     * You can also pass arbitrary arguments to the
     * context constructor through behat.yml.
     *
     * @param WebApi $webApi web api
     */
    public function __construct(WebApi $webApi, EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->webApi = $webApi;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;

    }





    /** @BeforeScenario */
    public function before(BeforeScenarioScope $scope)
    {

        echo 'before ';

        $loader = new Loader();
        $loader->addFixture(new LoadUserData());

        $purger = new ORMPurger();
        $executor = new ORMExecutor($this->entityManager, $purger);
        $executor->execute($loader->getFixtures());

    }
```

As you can see there is a function before. In it the last statement fails.

In Doctrine connection.php connect() function I have logged what parameters it is trying to use when connnecting:

```
file_put_contents('debug.txt', 'drive options: ' . json_encode($driverOptions) , FILE_APPEND);
```

and I see correct options. At least we do not notice what is incorrect in them. And also if they were incorrect, then all tests would fail if I comment out before() function, because they also connect to the database.

We are using docker container. I tried to login to mysql with any random string as user name to check:

```
mysql -u randomstr
```

and it connects with anything what I write as -u parameter. So I do not know how to check if my connect data is correct.

Btw I am not understanding what I am doing in before function, the colleague just said to use

https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures

for deleting records so I am trying to get some code running.

If you know better way, you can also tell.

The error is the following when I run test:

```
--- Failed hooks:

    BeforeScenario # tests\ApiBundle\features\group_management\bootstrap\CreatingNewGroupContext::before()
      │ before
      An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException)
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing: needed to add parameter to docker run script in behat file:

```
--net=host
```

Other db queries were running because it user diferent docker container and in docker run for that container this parameter was existing.

## this is from behat shell script file:

```
docker run --rm --sig-proxy=false --net=host -v ${APP_SRC_PATH}:${APP_DST_PATH} $APP_IMAGE bin/behat $@
```

And before() function:

```
/**
 * @BeforeScenario
 * @throws \Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException
 * @return null
 */
public function before()
{
    $stmt = $this->entityManager->getConnection()
        ->prepare("DELETE FROM `group` WHERE name = 'New group'");
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

entity manager is this:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
```